# import .sfb file is not opening in the asset Viewer window in android

Tags: android, android-studio

I  have used Sceneform ar in android. When i convert my .fbx file to **import Sceneform asset** , it is created successfully in raw folder & added in gadle file. But it can not open it looks like bellow error...

```
File loaded in wrong encoding:'UTF-8'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Update your sceneform plugin to version 1.12.0. Also update the respective sceneform version in your project's build.gradle and your app's build.gradle to version 1.12.0

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Google Sceneform Tools (Beta) plugin in order to view .sfb file.
Follow this guide from android-

https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/#import-sceneform-plugin

Comment: i have added plugin of Google Sceneform Tools (Beta)